# Load SVG content into DOM without Javascript

Tags: html, svg

Right now I have an external SVG file (sprites.svg) containing all my icons, that I am loading and injecting into the DOM using Javacript:

```js
$('<div></div>')
  .appendTo(container)
  .load('/images/sprites.svg')
  .hide();
```

The HTML injected into the DOM is something similar to this:

```html
<div style="display: none;">
  <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 60 60" id="icon1">...</symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 60 60" id="icon2">...</symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 60 60" id="icon3">...</symbol>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Then I am using this tag to include any icon I need on my website:

```html
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="#icon1"></use>
</svg>
```

Everything works fine, but since the icons are in the Critical Rendering Path, I would like to speed up the loading of the icons.

One solution would be to avoid doing an Ajax call to the sprites file and load it directly when we load the DOM.

I tried a couple of solutions but none of them work:

```html
<object data="/images/sprites.svg"></object> // -> Downloads the file

<embed src="/images/sprites.svg"></embed> // -> Creates an empty shadow DOM element
```

[image: object vs embed]

Any idea to solve this issue? Is it technically possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what about copying the svg content and but it into html? You can also use something like `file_get_contents` via php to load direkt from disk :)

Comment: Completely different and modern approach is by creating all SVG *client-side* and create **one single file** (or one script tag) for **all** Icon ``<path>`` data and Web Component script. Takes some out of the box thinking. See: https://iconmeister.github.io/

Comment: Are the icon animated or using JavaScript? If not you could use CSS to display them then the sprite sheet will be requested through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm picking up on your idea about including the SVG in an `<object>`. So when the SVG document is loaded into the `<object>` you can find the SVG document and replace the `<object>` with the contentDocument. So, kind of replacing itself. This requires a bit of JavaScript, but I guess it is OK now that it is not a AJAX request.

This must run from a web server and from same origin (I suppose...) to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        let object = document.querySelector('object');

        object.addEventListener('load', e => {
          e.target.outerHTML = e.target.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display:none">
      <object type="image/svg+xml" width="200" height="200" data="sprite.svg"></object>
    </div>
    <div>
      <svg>
        <use href="#icon1" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Well, you don't need to replace the original `<object>` but I just thought that it makes sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you do not have to support old browsers;
a modern `<svg-icon>` W3C standard Web Component can **create the SVG client-side**

If you define the Web Component (including icon path info) in the **<head>** of your HTML document, there are **zero extra downloads**.

##### All code required, to display 3 icons

```html
<svg-icon is="menu"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="settings"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="renew" rotate=45 fill=blue stroke=white></svg-icon>
```

[image]

##### is:

```html
<script>
((t,e={path:(t,e="")=>`<path d='${t}' ${e}/>`},r={v1:"",v2:"",v3:"",is:"",img:1,box:9,rect:"<rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='{tile}' {border}/>",border:"",filter:"",tile:"none",fill:"none",width:1,scale:1,opacity:1,rotate:0,stroke:"#000",xy:0,w:0,h:0,top:"",api:[t,e]})=>{customElements.define("svg-icon",class extends HTMLElement{static get observedAttributes(){return Object.keys(r)}attributeChangedCallback(){this.svg()}svg(i=this,s=i.A||Object.keys(i.A={...r}).map((t=>Object.defineProperty(i,t,{set:e=>i.setAttribute(t,e),get:()=>i.getAttribute(t)||getComputedStyle(i).getPropertyValue("--svg-icon-"+t).replace(/"/g,"").trim()||i.A[t]},e[t]=e=>(i.A[t]=e,"")))),l,a=(t[i.is]||"").split`;`.map((t=>([s,l]=t.trim().split`:`,e[s]?e[s].apply(i,l.split`,`):t))).join``,o=i.box/2,c=`<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 ${i.w||i.box} ${i.h||i.box}'>${i.rect}<g stroke-width='{width}' stroke='{stroke}' fill='{fill}' opacity='{opacity}' filter='{filter}' transform='translate({xy}) matrix({scale} 0 0 {scale} ${o-o*i.scale} ${o-o*i.scale}) rotate({rotate} ${o} ${o})'>${a}</g>${i.top}</svg>`.replace(/{\s?([^{}\s]*)\s?}/g,((t,e)=>i[e]))){return i.innerHTML=1==i.img?`<img src="data:image/svg+xml,${c.replace(/#/g,"%23")}">`:c}})})(
{
   menu:"box:9;path:m1.5 2.8h6m0 2h-6m0 2h6,stroke-linecap='round'",
   settings:"box:96;<circle stroke-width='12' cx='48' cy='50' r='26'/><circle stroke-width='12' cx='48' cy='50' r='36' stroke-dasharray='14'/>",
   renew:"box:96;fill:black;path:M48 24v12l16-16-16-16v12c-18 0-32 14-32 32 0 6 2 12 5 17L27 60A23 23 0 0 1 24 48c0-13 11-24 24-24zm26 6L69 37c2 3 3 7 3 11 0 13-11 24-24 24v-12l-16 16 16 16v-12c18 0 32-14 32-32 0-6-2-12-5-16z"
});
</script>

<style>
  svg-icon {
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: grey;
  }
  svg-icon:hover { background: lightgrey }
</style>

<svg-icon is="menu"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="settings"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is="renew" rotate=45 fill=blue stroke=white></svg-icon>
```

##### IconMeister

The `<svg-icon>` Web Component is fully documented at: https://iconmeister.github.io

Including **7347** icons extracted, and processed to JSON format, from all major Icon Sets:
Bootstrap, Feather, FontAwesome, Google Material, Eva, Radix, IBM Carbon, Linear, Vaadin and Clarity

So the site loads a bit slow, processing **7347** icons...

All `<svg-icon>` icons are configurable with **attributes**, **properties** and **CSS properties**

Web Component JavaScript code (excluding icons) by itself is only 800 GZipped Bytes.
But that will be less, because your whole HTML document is GZipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have static instance of what you are currently referencing through `svg:use` pointing at `symbol`'s ID, just pick the `symbol` from sprites.svg and place it into your HTML document's source as `svg` tag; i.e. what you have in SVG as `symbol` tag

```
<!-- original sprites.svg content around here -->
<symbol viewBox="0 0 60 60" id="icon1">...</symbol>
```

becomes `svg` tag in the HTML

```html
<!-- page.html content around here -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">...</svg>
```

(Better to always give it explicit `width` and `height`, BTW.)

If you are serving your page through HTTP2 (gzip) this is even the preferable way: possible repeated instances will be 'compressed out'. Look e.g. at GitHub pages: they are using no "sprites" at all and there are same chunks of SVG scattered around.

---

Your current approach without appending sprites.svg into html through JS would be like:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="./sprites.svg#icon1"></use></svg>
```

what should work in most modern browsers: `use` is specified to work this way, provided external SVG files are in the same origin as the document (what is prerequisity for ajax already). Appending it into HTML is just fix for some old/buggy browsers.